# Prove $\forall x \geq 0 : \mu\big((0,x]\big) = x\cdot\mu\big((0,1]\big)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu : \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow [0,\infty] $ be a translation-invariant measure, i.e. $\mu(A + a) = \mu(A)$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}).$ How would I show the following:

- $\forall x \geq 0 : \mu\big((0,x]\big) = x\cdot\mu\big((0,1]\big)$

So far I have shown that $\mu\left((0,\frac{p}{q}]\right) = \frac{p}{q}\cdot\mu\big((0,1]\big)$. Now I want to approach $x$ by a sequence of rationals, but I can't figure out exactly how to work it out, any tips?

Comment: Measures commute with limits of increasing/decreasing sequences of sets, so try to approximate  $x$ either from above or from below.

Comment: @AlexR. Thanks!